# PHP Header and Access-Control_Allow_Origin Error

Tags: php, javascript, header, cross-domain

I have two domains, leobee.com and txtease.com. I'd like to load a xml script from leobee.com  into a php page on txtease.com.  I was able to get the information to create the script below by researching stackoverflow site, However, I did not see how to fix this issue.

I've added php headers to the requesting script, and I'm getting "Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error.

Can you look at my script and let me know where I went wrong? The test script is live at:
http://txtease.com/crossdomain/scripts/example.html

in the chrome/ or firebug console use this:
createCORSRequest('GET', 'http://www.leobee.com/crossdomain/data/data.xml');

PHP script:

```
    <?php
echo "PHP Running";

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.leobee.com');

?>
<script>
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
var string;

function createCORSRequest(method, url) {


  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
    string ="with Credentials";
    xhr.onerror = function() {console.log('There was an error!')};
    xhr.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(string);

  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.send(null);
    string ="x domain request";
    xhr.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(string);

  } else if(!"withCredentials" in xhr){

     xhr.open(method, url, true);
     xhr.send(null);
     string ="with no Credentials";
     xhr.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(string);

  }else {

    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    alert("cross domain not supported");
    xhr = null;

  }

  return xhr;
}

function callbackFunction(string){

    console.log("Responding function: "+string);
      if (xhr.readyState == 4){
          var responseText = xhr.responseXML;
          console.log("xml string is: "+responseText);

        if (xhr.responseXML ===null){
                responseText=xhr.responseText;
                console.log("html string is: "+responseText);   

        }
      }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have `echo "PHP Running";`?  Remove that.  You can't echo anything before a `header()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving pages with the origin `http://www.leobee.com` permission to read data from `http://txtease.com/scriptExample.php`, but you need it to be the other way around.

The permission to read data has to come from the site that the data is coming *from*. A site can't grant itself permission to read data from arbitrary sites.

---

Also `echo "PHP Running";` will output content. You can't call `header` after you have output content.

Comment: I understand that I need to put the php header Access-Control_Allow_Origin in the same directory that has the xml file. And that I should remove the echo statement.  I'm confused as to how to put php in the xml file. I get error that says the xml decoration must be the first node in an xml document. I don't understand how to get the php file to run and the xml in one call.

Comment: The usual way is to give the XML file a `.php` file extension, then put your code between `<?php` and `?>` as normal. You also need to tell PHP to output the right content type (it defaults to HTML) with `header('Content-Type: application/xml');`.